# Finite extensions and group homology

Tags: group-theory, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, group-cohomology

I am working over $\mathbb{Q}$. I have read that if $H$ is a finite index normal subgroup in $G$, and $H_{i}(H;\mathbb{Q})$ has finite $\mathbb{Q}$-dimension, then $H_{i}(G;\mathbb{Q})$ has also finite $\mathbb{Q}$-dimension.

Nevertheless, the opposite does not hold; that is, $H_{i}(G;\mathbb{Q})$ having finite $\mathbb{Q}$-dimension does not imply that $H_{i}(H;\mathbb{Q})$ has finite $\mathbb{Q}$-dimension.

I was wondering if $\dim H_{i}(G;\mathbb{Q})\leq \dim H_{i}(H;\mathbb{Q})$? At least in some cases, where $i=1$, and so we care about the abelianization?

I have tried to use the transfer map, but I do not obtain anything... Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't understand what you say in "At least... and so" but yes for $i=1$, the inequality is true and easy. What proof do you know for the fact $\dim(H_i(H,\mathbf{Q}))<\infty\Rightarrow\dim(H_i(G,\mathbf{Q}))<\infty$?

Comment: Are you sure about your claim that the converse doesn't hold ? It seems to me that in the situation you describe, the two homologies are isomorphic (look at the Lyndon-Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence, which degenerates at page $2$ because of finite index)

Comment: @YCor Can you tell me how the proof works for $i=1$, please? I don't know any proof, I have only read it in https://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v170-n3-p11-p.pdf Page 1452 but I don't know the reason.

Comment: @Max In LHS we would have $H_{p}(G/ H ; H_{q}(H;\mathbb{Q}))\implies H_{p+q}(G;\mathbb{Q})$, but how can you say that they need to be isomorphic?

Comment: $H_q(H,\mathbb Q)$ is a $\mathbb Q$-vector spae and $G/H$ is finte, so $H_p(G/H, H_q(H, \mathbb Q)) =0$ if $p>0$ : the sequence degenerates at page $2$ an is concentrated in the $p=0$ line. Oh, my bad, there might still be an action of $G/H$ : $H_p(G, \mathbb Q)$ is $H_p(H, \mathbb Q)^{G/H}$ (the invariants), so they're not exactly isomorphic actually

Comment: If there is a surjective homomorphism $G\to\mathbf{Q}^k$, then we obtain by restriction a homomorphism of $H$ into a subgroup of finite index of $\mathbf{Q}^k$; but the only subgroup of finite index in $\mathbf{Q}^k$ is $\mathbf{Q}^k$ itself.

Comment: So, given that they are the invariants, the dimension is indeed smaller !

Comment: Uh wait, the coinvariants, not the invariants, obviously (i was thinking cohomologically). Of course, it doesn't change the conclusion about dimensions

Comment: @Max So the space of invariants and coinvariants have smaller dimension than the whole vector space? For the invariant case, is it because it is a quotient space of the actual vector space, and for the coinvariants because it is a subspace? Sorry for all my questions...

Comment: It's the other way around but yes : invariants are a subspace, coinvariants are a quotient; so they both have smaller dimension. Actually, here, since $|G/H|$ is invertible in $\mathbb Q$, they are isomorphic so have the same dimension (which is strictly smaller whenever the action is nontrivial)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lyndon-Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence has $E^2_{p,q} = H_p(G/H, H_q(H,\mathbb Q)) \implies H_{p+q}(G,\mathbb Q)$.

Since $G/H$ is finite, the $E^2$ term is $0$ for $p>0$, so the sequence degenerates at that page. It follows that $H_{q}(G,\mathbb Q) \cong H_0(G/H, H_q(H,\mathbb Q)) = H_q(H,\mathbb Q)_{G/H}$ (the coinvariants)

It follows that $H_*(G,\mathbb Q)$ is a quotient of $H_*(H,\mathbb Q)$, so it has a smaller dimension.

The same goes for cohomology, using this time invariant instead of co-invariants.

This could also provide a way to construct counter-examples to the converse statement : find an infinite dimensional $G/H$-module whose co-invariants are finite dimensional, and try to realize it as a group homology.

Here's an idea :

have $\mathbb Z$ act on $F\mathbb Z$ (the free group on generators $\mathbb Z$) by translation on generators; and $G$ the associated semi-direct product : $G=F\mathbb Z \rtimes \mathbb Z$, $H= F\mathbb Z \subset G$, and $G/H\cong \mathbb Z$.

Then $H_1(H,\mathbb Q) = \bigoplus_{n\in \mathbb Z}\mathbb Q$ (one for each generator) and $G/H$ acts on that by translating those summands, so that the $1$ in position $n$ becomes equal to the $1$ in position $n+1$ in the co-invariants : $H_1(H,\mathbb Q)_{G/H} \cong \mathbb Q$, which is of course finite-dimensional.

Comment: This is an amazing explanation. Thank you so much!